# Drush > ignore files and folders (ie : IDE conf) when pm-update

Tags: drush

Do you know if is there a way (by command argument, or in config) to ask drush not to remove IDE's configuration files and folder?

To be clear, Phpstorm create a .idea folder with project configuration in the root folder; when I run `drush pm-update drupal`, this folder is removed. Is there a way to ask drush to not delete this folder?

Comment: FWIW, I always have the base of my project one level up from Drupal root.  This way, my .idea, .git, Gruntfile, etc, don't have to live in DOCROOT and I never accidentally deploy them.

Comment: Yep, it could be a solution but how do you manage the cvs integration with phpstorm. The root of you repos is the drupal instance ? or the level up ?

Comment: All of my PHPStorm projects are in ~/Drupal, eg ~/Drupal/foo.com.  That is where the .idea and .git (or .svn) directory is.  ~/Drupal/foo.com/docroot has the actual site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  Drush always does a full directory replacement when upgrading a module with pm-update.  This insures that any files removed from the release do not remain on the disk after the update.  Contributions to improve drush in this area would be appreciated.

As a workaround, if you have your .idea folder checked into git, then you could always use `git checkout -- .idea` after pm-update to get it back.

Comment: Ok, thanks, in order to collect advices and ideas about that, I've created a github issue : https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/614

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, then I remembered that drush restores the directory **sites**, so you could locate all your permanent files inside that folder. Another option is to recover them from the backup drush does when updating...

I hope this helps